# Understanding bytearray from hex

Tags: python

Why this there is so difference in output with printing bytearray?

While example 1 seems fine to me. I don't understand why output of example 2 isn't `bytearray(b'\x2f')`?

```
# example 1
print(bytearray.fromhex('1f'))
# output bytearray(b'\x1f')

# example 2
print(bytearray.fromhex('2f'))
# output: bytearray(b'/')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `2f` is the ASCII code for the character `/`.

Comment: What should I do with my code to get expected output for example 2?

Comment: If you want it formatted a certain way, use the `format` function.

Comment: So it is not possible to have b'\x2f', am I correct?

Comment: You *could* override the `repr()` method to always display hex, or perhaps less drastically define a subclass with this behavior.

Comment: Okay, last thing to clarify. Why `print(type(bytearray.fromhex('10')[0]))` returns `int` instead of `bytes`. Isn't it counter intuitive for `bytearray` to return `int`?

Comment: You asked for the type of an *element* of a bytearray (the first element, to be exact).  So, if anything, the type would be `byte` (singular) -- but that isn't a type in Python.